# Async Folder creation callback never happens

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

I am doing a set of async operations in following oder

1. Read file
2. Create Folder
3. Write new file into that folder.

I have written my code using promise as follows.

```
const readMzFile = (fileName, type) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    fs.readFile(fileName, type, (err, data) => {
      return err ? reject(err) : resolve(data);
    })
  );

const createFolder = folderName =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    fs.mkdir(folderName, function(err) {
      return err ? reject(err) : resolve();
    })
  );

const writeMyFile = (filename, type) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    fs.writeFile(filename, type, function(err) {
      return err ? reject(err) : resolve();
    })
  );
```

and I am using those promise functions as follows

```
readMyFile("xxx", "utf8")
  .then(function(data) {
    var generated = anotherFunc(package_data, data);
    var dir = "/home/malintha/test";
    createFolder(dir).then(function() {
      writeMyFile("xxx", generated_source).then(function() {
        console.log("File saved !!");
        res.end();
      });
    });
  })
  .catch(error => console.log("Error: ", error));
```

Reading file and creating folder happen but final step - file writing is not done and seems like it stuck after folder creation.

What is the issue in this code?

Comment: Do you have appropriate permission for writing? also does it prints any error in catch block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, the promisified functions don't look bad (though maybe look into [`util.promisify()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) so you don't need to do that by hand).

At the very least, you're not returning the promises correctly, so exceptions might be hidden.

How about something like this?

```
readMyFile("xxx", "utf8")
  .then(function(data) {
    var generated = anotherFunc(package_data, data);
    var dir = "/home/malintha/test";
    return createFolder(dir)
      .then(() => writeMyFile("xxx", generated))
      .then(() => {
        console.log("File saved !!");
        res.end();
      });
  })
  .catch(error => console.log("Error: ", error));
```